# Can my own corporation deduct my expenses even if I am a full time employee?

Tags: canada, tax-deduction, contractor, expenses, corporation

Say I decide to become a software developer contractor and open a corporation. So, I am allowed to write certain things off as corporation expenses (e.g restaurant bills, gasoline bills, etc.)

Then, a company hires me full time, but I decide to keep the corporation. Would it then be illegal to write off my restaurant bills? Because I can still claim to be employed by my corporation, so I think it is legal.

Comment: I don't know how the law works in Canada, but I would be *very* surprised if you could write off restaurant bills as business expenses *if they don't relate to your work.* Your question seems to imply that you intend to write off *all* these expenses. Also, if you're employed full time by a company and aren't a contractor anymore, why would you be able to continue writing off contracting expenses? You're not a contractor.

Comment: If I am employed full time and do side jobs through my corporation, then I am still contractor and FT at the same time. No?

Comment: You would be considered both an employee and a contractor, yes. But you need to keep your income & expenses for each separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, your business cannot deduct your non-business expenses.  You can only deduct from your business income those reasonable expenses you paid in order to earn income for the business.

Moreover, for there to be a tax benefit, your business generally has to have income (but I expect there are exceptions; HST input tax credits come to mind.)

The employment income from your full-time job wouldn't count as business income for your corporation. The corporation has nothing to do with that income – it's earned personally, by you.

With respect to restaurant bills: These fall under a category known as "meals & entertainment".  Even if the expense can be considered reasonable and business-related (e.g. meeting customers or vendors) the Canada Revenue Agency decided that a business can only deduct *half* of those kinds of expenses for tax purposes.

With respect to gasoline bills: You would need to keep a mileage and expense log. *Only* the portion of your automobile expenses that relate to the business can be deducted.  Driving to and from your full-time job doesn't count.

Of course, I'm not a tax professional.  If you're going to have a corporation or side-business, you ought to consult with a tax professional.

(A point on terminology: A business doesn't *write off* eligible business expenses — it **deducts** them from business income.  *Write off* is an accounting term meaning to reduce the value of an asset to zero. e.g. If you damaged your car beyond repair, one could say "the car is a write-off.")